# PhotoSwipe with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, photoswipe

I've successfully implemented PhotoSwipe on a small gallery project of mine, following these instructions: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-lightbox-using-photoswipe-with-jquery--cms-23587

I would like to do it the Angular way instead though.

I've tried this https://github.com/m00s/angular-photoswipe , but the demo implementation just results in Unknown provider: bProvider <- b <- ngPhotoswipeDirective

Then I've played around with https://github.com/jsnmgpnty/angular-photoswipe for some time now and I managed to implement it partly. I'm not 100% fan of the way it's structured, but it seems to be the best one out there. But before I get in to deep I'm open to alternatives and suggestions!

**What's the best way to implement PhotoSwipe with Angular when it needs to be used on different repeated items with dynamic image content which can be modified?**